# Editing and importing storyboard changes from Xcode to Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, visual-studio-2015, xamarin.ios, xamarin-studio

I am moving my code from Xamarin Studio (Mac) to Visual Studio. I can open storyboard files in Xcode from Xamarin Studio. If I make changes in Xcode, close it, and open in Xamarin Studio, all of my changes are successfully imported including IBAction and IBOutlets. When I tried the same thing in Visual Studio, I could not see viewcontroller files to create IBOutlet and IBAction. Is this not supported in Visual Studio or am I missing something?

Comment: did you get any solution for this, as I am facing the same problem.

Answer (score -1):

No it not supported. If you need xcode sync, continue using Xam Studio Mac.