# Is it possible to import storyboard files from xcode to Visual Studio?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

has anyone been able to import storyboard files directly from xcode to visual studio without using XS as a middle man?
in other words, is it possible to open xcode , create a new storyboard file, drag and drop controls, arrange them however you like and then save it. No outlets or actions just the GUI stuff.
then copy the file over to VS and open it for editing.

I got an Objective-C exception when I opened it in VS.

Comment: This seems nearly identical to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36518727/editing-and-importing-storyboard-changes-from-xcode-to-visual-studio

Comment: indeed and I did come across this post before posting mine, but he is asking why the viewcontrollers and outlets/actions are missing and the reply was that syncing is not supported. That's fine. That wasn't my question. My question was: can it be edited. I will add the view controller files and outlets/actions myself manually. That's what I am trying to figure out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I was able to do that. I might have had a corrupted storyboard file when I got the Obj-C exception. 
This time I was to import multiple storyboard files over to VS.